# PostgreSQL not working with Node.js on Heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to work on a node.js application using Heroku and a PostgreSQL database.

I have followed the tutorial on Heroku documentation:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs#using-a-postgres-database

Dependencies are good, and my code is basically the following:

```
var pg = require('pg');

pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client) {
  var query = client.query('CREATE TABLE users (id bigint auto_increment not null, login varchar(250), constraint pk_users primary key (id) )');

  query.on('row', function(row) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
  });
});
```

I have tried various forms of this query, like this one:

```
var client = new pg.Client(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
client.connect();
```

But I got each time this error in my heroku logs:

```
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:875:19)
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
at errnoException (net.js:884:11)
```

If someone has already encountered this kind of problem, any help would be welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest trying a `console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL);`  and then using that address to manually connect using a client on your local machine. I understand that the Heroku database servers are open for remote connection(but I have been wrong before).

Failing that you can get a `heroku console` and use the postgre client.

ECONNREFUSED is a socket error that pops up when you try to connect to an address that is not contactable/connectable/listening.

If `process.env.DATABASE_URL` does return the correct and connectible address then I would be doing `console.log(pg);` to ensure that object is what I would expect it to be.

Comment: The real problem was the connection indeed. I have used the following method to do it instead: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#constructor. It works now. Thank you !